# Prove that $\frac{a^3}{b} + \frac{b^3}{a} \geqslant a^2 + b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that $$\frac{a^3}{b} + \frac{b^3}{a} \geqslant a^2 + b^2$$
> for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Establish when the equality holds.

My approach was to use AM-GM however trying both sides individually assert to $\geqslant 2ab.$ RHS is baby AM-GM if considered.

Edit:

From L.H.S -

$\dfrac{\frac{a^3}{b} + \frac{b^3}{a}}{2} \geqslant ab \implies \dfrac{a^3}{b} + \dfrac{b^3}{a} \geqslant 2ab$

Comment: You need to show some of your work.

Comment: Since you have chosen this line of proof, your next step would be to determine if $a^2+b^2\le2ab$ holds. Does it?

Comment: Try using [Titus-Lemma](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/titus-lemma-part-1/). Then AM-GM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce to this:

$(a-b)(a^3-b^3)\ge 0$

Do you see why it is always satisfied?

Comment: Yes, I can show that this always holds since a^3 - b^3 nicely factors and proving the other  factor (a^2 + ab + b^2) $\geqslant$ 0 is trivial enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Bring all terms to LHS$$\frac{a^3}b-\frac{a^3}a+\frac{b^3}a-\frac{b^3}b=(a^3-b^3)(1/b-1/a)$$
Now if $a\ge b$, both factors are $\ge0$. When $a<b$, both are negative. Can you see when the equality holds?

Comment: [fyi](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick, using **only** AM-GM, twice.
$$a^2+b^2\geq 2ab \Rightarrow \\
\frac{a^3}{b}+\color{red}{a^2}+\frac{b^3}{a}+\color{red}{b^2} \geq 
\frac{a^3}{b}+\color{red}{ab}+\frac{b^3}{a}+\color{red}{ab}\geq\\
2\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{b}\cdot ab} + 2\sqrt{\frac{b^3}{a}\cdot ab}=2a^2+2b^2$$
Or
$$\frac{a^3}{b}+\color{blue}{a^2}+\frac{b^3}{a}+\color{blue}{b^2} \geq 2(\color{blue}{a^2+b^2})$$
and the result follows.